# Diagonal intersection of quadrat

Tags: geometry

A square $ABCD$ is divided by a straight line $g$ into two parts with the same surface area.
Prove that then the diagonal intersection $M$ of the square $ABCD$ lies on the line $g$.

Comment: "Surface area" applies to a three-dimensional shape. Do you mean "area"? Or perhaps "perimeter", the total length of the sides?

Comment: By "diagonal intersection", you mean the center of the square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose by contrary. i.e. $M$ is out side of $g$. draw a line from $M$ to one of intersections of $g$ with square $ABCD$. Then this segment and two vertices of square divide square in two equal part such that $g$ is is one side of this segment (i.e. in one part). this is a contradiction. because $g$ also divides the square in two  equal part.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on @C.F.G: suppose $M$ is not in $g$. Take the line $g'$ parallel to $g$ which does contain $M$. $M$ is the center of the square, so by symmetry, $g'$ divides the square into two equal parts. But there's a strip of positive area between $g$ and $g'$, so $g'$ does not divide the square into two equal parts, which is a contradiction.

Comment: your answer is very clear than mine.